# why is my multi-threaded task not working as it should?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I am trying to get posts from facebook using batch operations. 
i thought about making this task multi-threaded to speed up operation.
basically , im sending batch requests to facebook and while waiting for the response my task is doing other things that need to be done.
when i debug the task (slowly) i get the 2000results i want to get for the test....
but when i run it or let it debug and pause after the request operation , it gets less than 2000.

```
    String[] str = new String[2000];
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<BatchRequest> request= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<BatchRequest>();
    List <BatchResponse> batchResponses = new ArrayList<BatchResponse>();



    int i=1;
    for(int j=0 ; j<2000; j++) {

        if (i < 50) {
            BatchRequest batch = new BatchRequestBuilder(str[i]).build();
            request.add(batch);
            i++;
            counter++;
        } else {
            i = 1;
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {

                //thread that gets information from facebook into a list of responses
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("running");
                    batchResponses.addAll(fc.executeBatch(request));
                    System.out.println("done");

                }

            });
            request.clear();
        }
    }
    exec.shutdown();
    exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

i have deleted all that is not necessary . hope it still makes sense.

whats wrong with my code?

EDIT: ive edited the code to make more sense. anyone?

Comment: It might be helpful to create an example that illustrated the same issue with out the database logic (i.e. instead of while rs.next() create a loop that iterates 2000 times and instead of creating the batchResponses array create an array of strings, etc.).  This would give us code we could execute and debug directly instead of having to make these modifications ourselves to reproduce the issue you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @OldCurmudgeon answer I can say that `ArrayList` is not thread safe class. You can use other container, wrap it with `Collections.synchronizedList()` or add synchronization to your code.

Also make sure that your `fc` variable reference to thread safe class.

Comment: i dont see why should it be a problem , i dont use the arrayList anywhere near the thread related code .... i only insert into it and at the end of the code im moving the info from it to the database.

fc is a DefaultFacebookClient from restfb. i dont think it is thread safe. how do i make it "thread safe"?

and as i told OldCurmudgeon..... nothing is wrong about counter and i.
this code works perfectly fine when debugged slowly , stepbystep.

Comment: seems like i didnt make my point clear. 
i ment that the arrayList im inserting into shouldnt be a problem and im only getting information from it much later. and again , dosent seem to be the problem.
ive edited the code. hope it helps

Comment: You access to `batchResponses` from several different threads. There is such thing as Java Memory Model. It is about guarantees JVM provide. One of them is *visibility*. It is about changes made in one tread is visible from other. By default JVM not guarantee visibility. You need to make special effort to achieve it. For example use synchronization.

Comment: ive made what ever i can about it. maybe i missed something? 
for now , `batchResponses` and request are now wrapped in `Collections.synchronizedList`
and are`CopyOnWriteArrayList`....
yet , the code is messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion in your code between `counter` and `i`. Perhaps if you explain why you need both of these things would become clearer.

As the code stands the main problem is that you are never setting `counter` back to zero. This will cause the first 500 to be executed as one batch in its own thread but each of the rest of them will be executed on their own.

Comment: the counter is only cause the database im using has 100,000~ rows and i wanna test on only 500.
no confusion about that.
as i said , if ill debug it slowly (with few step by steps clicks) it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:
batchResponses is being accessed inside the thread as well as you are pushing in it in your main thread. Also batchResponses is not thread safe, so needs to be synchronize this.

Also you do request.clear in the main thread...This is bug as you cant gurantee that new thread has executed, it may be case that new thread run after you cleared it. And new thread will see request.size(0) = 0.

The main if block and else block have same thread code which is bit confusing.
if(i== 50) you get in else block and execute requests.
when your counter is 500, you already have visited the else block 10 times so you may have empty request or the last 50 that you inserted.

Somethings are not clear in this code.

Comment: im aware of how confusing my code is but thats not the final stage of my code... it got so confusing when i tried fixing the bug i am talking about here.
about the the two blocks having same code , thats (as i said) because im running a test on 500 rows from my resultset and not the whole resultset that is much much bigger.

about clearing the request while the thread is using it - ive read somewhere that this is okay as long as im using the right object (CopyOnWriteArrayList in this case)
if you think this is the problem , what is the solution? what other way do you suggest?

Comment: i have edited the code to make more sense. please have another look